# Listening to onpopstate event on vuejs

Tags: vue.js, popstate

I'm quite new to Vue and I'm trying to figure out how to listen to the onpopstate event on vuejs to start a specific function when it occurs. I went through the router documentation but I can't find an equivalent for the onpopstate event handler on vue.

Thanks for the help,
Will

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html would be what you're looking for, I'd think. `router.beforeEach` /  `router.afterEach` functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `vue-router` in an SPA then I would just place it in the created hook of the base component:

```
  created() {
    // Attach onpopstate event handler
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
    };
  },
```

Because the base component serves up all views, you should find that the event will fire throughout your entire app.

Here's the JSFiddle to show you how this setup would work: https://jsfiddle.net/bjb8ukb8/

Comment: Ohhh ! I get it, I was doing something wrong : I was switching component and not using the router-view, I changed a few things and it works and my code is SO much nicer like this, Thanks !

Comment: Your code does not work. Event onpopstate is never fired so no alert is executed. I tested similar code in my app but alert also is never fired. Maybe VUE router changes history in strange way because when I navigate manually location.hash="/sth" onpopstate is fired correctly.